# logical cursor movement in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-cursor

How to enable logical cursor movement for bidirectional texts in notepad++? Like Notepad on Windows.

Now when I start moving through text using arrow keys on keyboard after reaching a RTL sentence embedded in the LTR text it's difficult to select a word within this sentence because I visually see that the text cursor is on another word and I should see how far the word is from the start of sentence and then use the Ctrl+Arrow to skip words one by one until I reach the proposed word.